# Convergence/absolute convergence of a series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi n/6)}{n^p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi n/6)}{n^p}$$

I need to find out for what values of $p$ the sum converges; 
and also for which $p$ it converges $absolutely$.

I found that it converges absolutely if $p>1$, by comparing the absolute value of the sum to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^p$. But I am unsure if this means the sum only converges (absolutely or not) for $p>1$. Should I use another test for this?

Comment: The absolute convergence test only gives you *sufficient conditions* for convergence. For example, consider $\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n / n=-\log 2$. The absolute series associated to this sum is the Harmonic series (which diverges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already proved that it converges absolutely for $p>1$.

**Hint**.

- By using [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), one proves that this series also
  converges for $0<p\leq1$.

  This may be seen from the fact that $$ n \mapsto \frac1{n^p} $$ is
  decreasing to $0$ and from the fact that $$ \left|\sum_{n=1}^N
     \cos(\pi n/6)\right|=\left|\Re \sum_{n=1}^N e^{i\pi
     n/6}\right|=\left|\Re \frac{e^{i\pi/6}\left(1-e^{iN\pi/6}
     \right)}{1-e^{i\pi/6} }\right|\leq \frac{2}{\cos (\frac{\pi}{12})}.
     $$
- The case $p\leq0$ is clear, we have $$ \lim_{n \to
     \infty}\frac{\cos(\pi n/6)}{n^p} \neq0 $$ and the series is
  divergent.

*Remark*. You are left with studying the behaviour of $\displaystyle \sum\frac{|\cos(\pi n/6)|}{n^p} $ as $0<p\leq1$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very useful test! It would seem my textbook doesn't refer to it, however, so I probably wouldn't be allowed to refer to it in my course. But my book does refer to the alternating series test. Could the proof be modified to use this test instead? I tried using this test, but had trouble with the condition that $|a_{n}|>|a_{n+1}|$ since cos oscillates

Comment: Thanks. But the alternating series test does not apply here, since $\cos(\pi n/6)$ is not really alternating... That why we refer to Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Have you already seen summation by parts? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood something then. I thought it must alternate because cos takes on values between -1 and 1, but this is not the case? I don't recognize summation by parts, I think my course might be a bit more elementary

Comment: Usually a series $u_n=(-1)^n a_n$ is called 'alternating series' if there exists $a_n$ with a *constant sign* such that $u_n=(-1)^n a_n$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks